# Always getting "Application in break mode" error when trying to debug xamarin.android application

Tags: xamarin.android

I am developing a Xamarin.Android Application in Visual studio 2017 (V:15.4.1). MY application has few pages like. 
1) Splash 
2) Login 
3) Dash Board
........ Other Pages. 
When i run the app in debug mode. It shows the login page and after entering credential it shows process-bar and check user credential from external Service Using "HttpClient" in Async.

Then main issues arise after this operation. 
[image]

*** If i run the app in debug mode. it shows **Application in break mode** 
*** If i run normally this app in android device. it works fine.

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: 1. Check your call stack. If it contains "External code" then right click on that and click on "Show external code". 2. Check your local. 3. Write $exception in immediate window. 4. Check debug output. 5. Try with both "Just my code" enabled & disabled.

Comment: @YaserMoradi okey , i am checking my application and let you know about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the toast notification you need to run that line inside the main thread.

You can do this by

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {

 //put your toast line in here.. 
 Toast.MakeText(this, "Login Succesfull", ToastLength.Long).Show();

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sFirstCharacter == "1")
            {
                var MainActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                MainActivity.PutExtra("Value", txtusername.Text);
                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
                //Toast.MakeText(this, "Login Succesfull", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    progress.Dismiss();
                });
            }
```

After commenting Toast from IF condition it working fine :)

Comment: Yess. i realized that and removed toast .